# Python not finding matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit 
(Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
>>>
```

I need to create a graph but I'm not sure why python isnt finding matplotlib

Comment: `pip install matplotlib`

Comment: gives me invalid syntax on the word install

Comment: That's (above comment) a command for the shell/cmd. Not python code! Read some very basic introduction to python, including how to install software. You will probably run into more problems on windows using the scientific stack (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, ...) later. Make sure you are prepared!

Comment: Have you actually installed matplotlib?

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed the library on your system. You could install it by running `pip install matplotlib` on your shell/command line. (you could also install it from withon python by the command `import pip; pip.main(["install", "matplotlib"])`.

Answer (score -1):

I have sometimes encountered this when not referencing the correct sub-library

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

Comment: Oh no, this is not how to install matplotlib!

Comment: D'oh, meant import  @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Ok, but if `import matplotlib` already fails, why should `import matplotlib.pyplot` suddenly work? (That's a rethorical question.) Hence this is not really helpful. Don't be disappointed, it's not really your fault; sometimes questions are simply not answerable because of missing information.

Comment: I've scratched that and downloaded canopy, it comes with it